# Why does my widget in oh-my-zsh does not exist although I can see it if displaying widget based on keybinding?

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I try to add a widget to `zsh`. I am using `oh-my-zsh`. If I check the keybinding to which I assigned my widget It shows me the correct widget. But if I list all widgets I cannot see the widget to which I assigned the keybinding. My expected result is that I can see the widget but instead I cannot see the widget. If I try to call the widget with my assigned keybinding I get an error.

**Displaying widget based on keybinding**

`bindkey "^d"` >> `"^D" create_completion`

**listing widgets**

`zle -al.` >> displays list of widgets (does not contain `create_completion`)

**Calling widget with keybinding**

`^d` >> `` No such widget `create_completion' ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had defined in my `.zshrc` file already earlier my plugins variable wich overwrote the plugins variable where I defined my widget from which the error occurred. All the plugins need to be written in one plugin variable.

In `.zshrc` file:

**Wrong**

```
plugins=(git)
plugins=(zsh_copilot)
```

**Correct**

`plugins=(git zsh_copilot)`

Comment: You **can** have it in two lines, if you prefer it for clarity, but you have to use then `+=` instead of `=`.